# regex match and replace in vscode for repetitive pattern

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have this svg

```
<circle id="a/b/c" stroke="#2C2C2C" stroke-width="2" fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero" cx="141" cy="21" r="9"/><text id="a/b/c-something" font-size="10" fill="#2C2C2C"><tspan x="0" y="10">a/b/c Something</tspan></text>
```

I want to replace `id="a/b/c"` to `id="a-b-c"` in the `circle` and also
`id="a/b/c-something"` to `id="a-b-c-something"` in `text`
and exclude `a/b/c Something` from being replaced.

I'm using vscode, and I've tried `(id=.+)\/(.+)` but it doesn't seem to match it properly. I want to

Comment: Please try this: id="([a-zA-Z_\-\/]*)"

Comment: @MarkusMeyer nice, but sometime the id can also be id="ab/cd/ee-something-123"

Comment: Are you using the *file search and replace* or *in-document search and replace* feature?

Comment: in document search and replace

Comment: id="ab/cd/ee-something-123": =>     id="([0-9a-zA-Z_\-\/]*)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic way to do this is to match and capture the part before the first qualifying `/` char, match this char without capturing, and then match the part on the right to ensure the context is correct, and then replace with Group 1 value + new char + Group 2 value.

The general scheme is

```
Find:    (left-hand context)text to remove/replace(right-hand context)
Replace: $1new_text$2
```

Then repeat until no more changes are made to the document.

In your case, you can use

**Find What**:   `(\sid="[^"/]*)/([^"]*"[^>]*>)`
**Replace With**: `$1-$2`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qEnRZA/1). *Details*:

- `(` - Group 1:

  - `\s` - a whitespace
  - `id="` - a fixed text
  - `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than a `"` char
- `)` - end of Group 1
- `/` - a `/` char
- `(` - Group 2:

  - `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than `"`
  - `"`  - a `"` char
  - `[^>]*` - zero or more chars other than `>`
  - `>` - a `>` char
- `)` - end of Group 2.

This will work for both *File search and replace* and *In-document search and replace* feature.

If you are applying the regex against a single document using *In-document search and replace* feature, you can make use of a lookaround-based pattern to achieve the goal in a single pass:

**Find What**:   `(?<=\sid="[^"]*)/(?=[^"]*"[^>]*>)`
**Replace With**: `-`

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qEnRZA/2). *Details*:

- `(?<=\sid="[^"]*)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with

  - `\s` - a whitespace
  - `id="` - a fixed text
  - `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than a `"` char
- `/` - a `/` char
- `(?=[^"]*"[^>]*>)` - a positive looahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with

  - `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than `"`
  - `"`  - a `"` char
  - `[^>]*` - zero or more chars other than `>`
  - `>` - a `>` char.